# Recently viewed products are cached and not updated in custom container

Tags: magento2

I have added the /etc/widget.xml, to call the recently viewed in Footer container.The recently viewed block is display but it's applied with cache so the newly viewed products are not updated.

The Recently viewed section is getting updated, Only after the cache is flushed.

```
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
     <widget id="catalog_recently_viewed" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\RecentlyViewed"
            placeholder_image="Magento_Catalog::images/product_widget_viewed.gif"> 
        <containers> 
             <container name="footer">
                <template name="grid" value="grid" />
                <template name="list" value="list" />
            </container> 
        </containers>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

Comment: I have a feeling that the footer is cached. Try placing it somewhere else (content of the page) and see if it's still cached.

Comment: Thanks. I resolved the issue by using widget and cms block concept.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by using widget and cms block concept. Since widget is working via the ajax request, that's a power of widget!.

### Magento 2.2.7 Version

Step 1:
Module file path : root/app/Code/Faceless/RecentlyViewed/Setup/UpgradeData.php

```
<?php

namespace Faceless\RecentlyViewed\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{


    private $blockFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory $blockFactory
    ) {
        $this->blockFactory = $blockFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $cmsblockModel = $this->blockFactory->create()->load(
            'recently_viewed', 'identifier'
        );
        $cmsblockModel->getId() ? $cmsblockModel->delete() : '';        
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
            $cmsBlockData = [
                'title' => 'Recently viewed',
                'identifier' => 'recently_viewed',
                'content' => '{{widget type='
                . '"Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\RecentlyViewed"'
                . ' uiComponent="widget_recently_viewed" page_size="5" '
                . 'show_attributes="name,image,price" show_buttons="add_to_cart"'
                . ' template="product/widget/viewed/grid.phtml"}}',
                'is_active' => 1,
                'stores' => [0, 1, 2],
                'sort_order' => 0
            ];
            $this->blockFactory->create()->setData($cmsBlockData)->save();
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

---

Step 2: 
Module file path : root/app/Code/Faceless/RecentlyViewed/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <container name="footer.recent" as="footerRecent" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="recently-viewed-wrap" before="-">
                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="Recentlyviewed">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">recently_viewed</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

---

Step 3: 
Module file path : root/app/Code/Faceless/RecentlyViewed/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Faceless_RecentlyViewed" setup_version="1.0.1" schema_version="1.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

---

Step 4: 
Module file path : root/app/Code/Faceless/RecentlyViewed/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Faceless_RecentlyViewed',
    __DIR__
);
```